# python multiprocessing; one processor for all values of each dictionary key

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

In general, using pool and starmap, if we have

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
        temp_arr = p.starmap(process, tuple_list)
```

tuple_list = [(1,2), (3, 4)], e.g., results in process(1,2) and process(3,4), each assigned to a different processor.

If I have:

```
dict = {'0': [(1,1), (2,3)], '1': [(4,4)], '2': [(2,4), (3,5)]}:
```

is there a way I can use Pool so that all values of key '0' go to the first processor in one go (as a tuple-list [(1,1), (2,3)], e.g., so that I can process each tuple separately inside process() later on), key '1' values goes to the second processor and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to use `map(process, dict.values())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` with `dict.values()`

```
import multiprocessing as mp

dict = {
     '0': [(1,1), (2,3)], 
     '1': [(4,4)], 
     '2': [(2,4), (3,5)]
}

def process(data):
    print(f"process data: {data}")
    #return result

with mp.Pool() as p:
    all_results = p.map(process, dict.values())
```

Result:

```
process data: [(1, 1), (2, 3)]
process data: [(4, 4)]
process data: [(2, 4), (3, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
dict = {'0': [(1,1), (2,3)], '1': [(4,4)], '2': [(2,4), (3,5)]}

def process(tup):
    print(f"input tuple: {tup} -- worker_id: {mp.current_process()}\n")
    time.sleep(2)

def process_all(index):
    for tup in dict[index]:
        process(tup)

with mp.Pool() as p:
    temp_arr = p.starmap(process_all, dict.keys())

# Result
#input tuple: (1, 1) -- worker_id: <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-121, started daemon)>
#input tuple: (2, 4) -- worker_id: <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-123, started daemon)>
#input tuple: (4, 4) -- worker_id: <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-122, started daemon)>
#input tuple: (3, 5) -- worker_id: <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-123, started daemon)>
#input tuple: (2, 3) -- worker_id: <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-121, started daemon)>
```

This is exactly what you want to ?

Comment: From your Result, it seems this should also work for my problem. However, when I ran the code, there is an error at "p.starmap(process_all, dict.keys())", the error being "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable." It's entirely possible, I may be doing something wrong. Thanks anyway.